# Выбор окончания

Tags: грамматика, согласование, словосочетания

Как правильно написать *вид занятия*: практический или практическое?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно же, склоняется не окончание, а одиночное слово (занятие) или словосочетание (практическое занятие).
Здесь речь идет о **согласовании** — виде связи, при котором зависимое слово (прилагательное *практическое*) согласуется с главным (существительным *занятие*) в роде, числе и падеже.

[Занятие](https://endic.ru/ozhegov/Zanjatie-9309.html), -я (средний род, ед. число, И. п. или В. п.) — *как**ое**?* — практическ**ое**.

При этом Макаров вспоминал своего учителя адмирала Г. И. Бутакова, который, организуя **практическое занятие** по маневрированию, заставлял корабли ходить по рейду, описывая вокруг стоящих судов различной формы кривые. [Б. Г. Островский. Адмирал Макаров (1949-1955)]

*— Он вел **практическое занятие**. Инструктировал оперативников — как выявлять скрытых Иных. Наткнулся на меня...* (Сергей Лукьяненко. Ночной дозор).

[Виды связи в словосочетаниях](https://russkijyazyk.ru/vidy-svyazi-v-slovosochetaniyah)